# Quantum gravity and inspirals by emission of gravitational waves

Tags: quantum-gravity, gravitational-waves

Should we expect that quantum gravity, just as quantum theory forbids the decay of the fundamental level, avoids the collision of gravitationally bound systems at small scales, despite they emit gravitational radiation/waves? In other words, should we expect that quantum gravity will avoid gravitational wave emission above the fundamental level?

Comment: What do you mean by fundamental level?